# Run startupscript on Fedora 8 Core

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, fedora

I'm using Amazon EC2 with a Fedora 8 Core AMI. I have an EBS volume mounted at /ebsmnt, and a startupscript located at /ebsmnt/startupscript.sh . Currently I have to login to the server, cd to /ebsmnt/ and run the script manually. How can I make Fedora run this script automatically at startup, without any interaction from me? (by having it on /ebsmnt/ I don't have to recompile the AMI everytime I wish to make changes to the script). I'm not too familiar with *nix, so a step by step guide would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the file /etc/rc.local are executed on startup.
note:  You will have to add the full path to the script.

Does the script understand the "Start" and "Stop" parameters?  If so it could be added to the runlevels.

Comment: Don't know about start/stop, but adding the line to /etc/rc.local works. Thanks!